# Back button on Navigation controller dont stop video streaming (IOS)

Tags: iphone, ios, button

When i push Back button on Navigation controller app is successfully return to the controller view, but dont stop video streaming.

I write:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setDescText:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];

    [moviePlayerController stop];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}
```

but not help.

Please, give me advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`viewDidUnload` is only called in low-memory conditions. You want `viewDidDisappear`.

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

[UIViewController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: That's just what I need ! Thank you !